# How to extract string/value from Promise Object in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to get value from Promise Object in Browser console 
When i input some data in TextInput and trying to get from another page using Asyncstorage i receive a Promise Object with value (Hello) inside it. For example

`Promise {_40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null}
_40: 0
_65: 1
_55: ""Hello"" 
_72: null__proto__: Object`

My Code is

```
onPress = ()=>{
  this.setState({FromStr: this.state.From})
  this.fetch();
 }
 fetch(){
   AsyncStorage.setItem('value', JSON.stringify(this.state.From)).then(Message.message())
}
```

//Page 2 From where i receive the value in console

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
export default class Message extends Component {

     static message=()=>{
     console.log(AsyncStorage.getItem('value'))
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('value', function (err, value) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(value)) 
}
```

Comment: It throws an error "Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0"
A is my first character of string

Answer (score 0):

You need await or .then().catch() 
await is better but youll also need try catch to catch unfulfilled promises

```
static message = async () => console.log(await AsyncStorage.getItem('value'))
```

Comment: I  didn't receive any log

Comment: You need to call it since its an anonymous function
message()